# How to use Zookeeper with Azure HDInsight Linux cluster?

Tags: azure, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-zookeeper, azure-hdinsight

Obviously I need to start a zookeeper server on one of the cluster machines, then I need other client machines to connect to this server.
The way I did it is that I used ssh to connect to the headnode, I found a zk server running on the port 2181. So, I used ifconfig to get the machine's IP address (for example 10.0.0.8) and i then had my worker nodes connect to:
10.0.0.8:2181.
However, my MR job now completes but it works slowly and the output is not correct. I suspect that I'm doing something wrong with Zookeeper, especially that I didn't follow a tutorial and improvised my steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDInsight has multiple zookeeper servers. Not sure if specifying one might be the cause of the problem you are seeing.

I wrote an example a while back that uses Storm to write to HBase (both servers on the same Azure Virtual Network,) and as part of the configuration, I had to specify the three zookeeper servers for the component that writes to hbase. (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-storm-sensor-data-analysis/ is the article.)

From the cluster head node, you can probably ping zookeeper0, zookeeper1, and zookeeper2 to find the IP address of each.